# How do I pipe the output of find command to ffmpeg as a input

Tags: ffmpeg, find, pipe

I have a video archive and i need to find the file in the archive and then output of the file must be used as input for `ffmpeg`.

```
find /mnt/video-archieve -name 'file'.mov | ffmpeg -i - ...
```

I know `-` is mainly used for piping the input to `ffmpeg` but I am missing some other parameters to make it work.

I have tried several option but couldn't Get it work.

Comment: when i run this command i get this error :

`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

```
find /mnt/video-archieve -name "file.mov" -exec ffmpeg -i {} \;
```

or

```
find /mnt/video-archieve -name "file.mov" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} ffmpeg -i {}
```

or

```
find /mnt/video-archieve -name "file.mov" -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' file; do \
        ffmpeg -i "$file"; \
    done
```

or

```
find /mnt/video-archieve -name "file.mov" -print0 | \
    while IFS= read -d '' file; do \
        ffmpeg -i "$file"; \
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot man!! you have saved me. i am trying to make work since days.

Big Thanks. I owe you :)

Comment: @kunal As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Just last Question , i am making a PHP website. how can i get the Output Stream to the Web page. if you have any idea about it.

Comment: i did man, i also have voted up but because of my reputation it didnt show up.

Comment: @kunal Sorry, please no new questions in comments. Ask a new question, this is also good for your reputation score. **;)**

Comment: Thanks For the Tip @A.B , today i got my reputation Up from my question and your Answer.

thanks Again Man for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

Another short answer:

```
for f in "/mnt/video-archieve/file.mov" ; do ffmpeg -i "$f" ... ; done
```

Comment: hi @Maythux! 
thanks a lot for the Another Solution.
i will have to use this command from the web. In my environment user will Put the File id and i will search this ID on the Shell with SSH2_EXEC Function of PHP and the solution of @ A.B works perfect for my need.

i will give a try to your way also and let you know if this solve my issue.

Comment: @kunal you are welcome friend